# Unknown word error when import css file

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js, css-loader

I'm trying to import material icons for my project (following instruction in: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/icons)

nuxt.config.js

```
...
extend(config, {isDev, isClient, isServer}) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
          },
          {
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000
            }
          }
        )
      }
      if (isServer) {
        config.externals = [
          nodeExternals({
            whitelist: [/^vuetify/]
          })
        ]
      }
    }
...
```

But when I try to run the project, this error appears:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                     4:05:21 PM

 error  in ./node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css

Module build failed: Syntax Error

(2:1) Unknown word

  1 | 
> 2 | var content = require("!!../../css-loader/index.js!./material-design-icons.css");
    | ^
  3 | 
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];


 @ ./node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css 4:14-188 13:3-17:5 14:22-196
 @ ./plugins/vuetify.js
 @ multi vue vue-router vue-meta vuex vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient css-loader/lib/css-base ~/plugins/vuetify.js
```

My vuetify.js file

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Vue from 'vue'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

I have no idea what I did wrong, please help me to point it out. Many thanks.

Comment: You tried using the css prop in nuxt.config.js?
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css/

Comment: Also tried, same error @Allkin

Answer (score 0):

So the way I resolve this problem is add it according to @Allkin's comment:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
css: [
    '~/assets/style/app.styl',
    'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
  ],
```

Also I removed this in **nuxt.config.js**, otherwise it still have the same error

```
{
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000
    }
  }
```